# Tricky Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory

(Komal November B. 4663)

Find the integer solutions of the equation $2x^3-y^3=5$.

Hint: use modulo / remainders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any integer $w$,  $w^3$ is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $-1$ modulo $9$. Taking all possible cases, we find that $2x^3-y^3$ is congruent to one of $0$, $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$, or $\pm 3$ modulo $9$. In particular, it cannot be congruent to $5$ modulo $9$.